# Making a quiz with live refreshing on client side

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, multiple-choice

I am making a quiz in PHP, javascript (AJAX), MySQL, HTML5, CSS3 etc.

**How it works now:**

There are two roles in the quiz;

- The quizmaster (who leads the quiz)
- (20 people on iPads) The participant (Who answers the multiple choice answers)

In the database, the quizmaster updates the question number.

**Example:**

All the devices(iPads) continually ask the database which question-number they are on at the moment (with AJAX request).
When the quizmaster updates the number of the question all those devices get the right question on their screens.

This requires too much data from the database, which is why the database fails to return all the data and sometimes gives a error back.

**Question**

So my question is; if there are people who have a better solution for making a quiz with PHP, javascript and AJAX without a plug-in or whatever. With (!important) live refreshing on client(iPad) side.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All those unrelated tags ....without even 1 line of code

Comment: you could implement a socket connection, so that the clients can be told when a question arrives, instead of continuously asking for it